# Java's JDB (and Eclipse) hang when connecting to remote JVMs with many threads (i.e. transmitting thread debug information via TCPIP)

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging, jvm-hotspot, jdb

### Problem Description

Hi everyone,

I was having problems remote debugging to a new server today and it initially appeared as if Eclipse was taking a long time to connect to a remote JVM. However, after some investigation I realized `jdb` was having a similar problem. Some digging turned up this...

**Connecting to the remote JVM is not a problem.** Both debuggers establish the socket connection properly within a few seconds. `jdb` even processes commands. However, after a remote debugger has connected to it successfully, the `Sun Java 1.7.0_60-b19 JVM` appears to be hanging (or transmitting extremely slowly) when sending its thread debugging information (JVMTI/JDWP) across the network via TCPIP.

**Listing the remote JVM's threads appears to be the problem.** JDB's `threads` command either hangs or executes extremely slowly. The load on the remote JVM is reasonable, and there aren't any breakpoints set. There are many threads executing on this JVM concurrently (~2005 threads), and there may be some WAN latency, but there still needs to be a way to successfully use a remote debugger with it!

**Observation.** I'm guessing this is related to inefficient transmission of thread information via TCPIP by the JVM's Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP) implementation, as the machine *is* on the other side of the planet on a WAN. HOWEVER -- Windows Remote Desktop Connection to the same machine is acceptably fast and performant. Given that, it seems that having to wait 45 minutes for Eclipse or `JDB` to list thread information on a JVM is unacceptable and likely a bug (or a very poorly implemented feature).

**Possibly related to?**

1. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6401245 - This
   looks like it was fixed and shouldn't be the issue anymore. Plus the JVM is running on Windows Datacenter not Linux.
2. http://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/comment/reply/1153.html - Possible
   solution but requires the SAP JVM?
3. https://github.com/vpotapev/jbreakpoint - Open source jdb interface
   but doesn't fix issue with Eclipse.

**Question.** Does anyone have any ideas how to make the thread data transmission more efficient so the JVM can be remote debugged effectively? Is this a bug in the JVM's Java Debugging Wire Protocol (JDWP)?

### Problem Details

**Java Version:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java" -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

**Application Server.** Happens with Weblogic 10g. Also happens with IBM WebSphere 8.5

**Eclipse.** Eclipse remote debugging hangs indefinitely when trying to populate the Debug view with thread information.

**JDB - Remote.** Java's `jdb` remote debugger hangs for upwards of 10 minutes when listing the threads with the `thread` command. Then it lists them VERY slowly (1 thread per second, would take 33 minutes to list them all).

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\jdb.exe -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=xxx.yyy.com,port=7777
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Initializing jdb ...
> threads
Group system: <<jdb hangs here trying to get thread information>>
```

**JDB - Local.** Java's `jdb` remote debugger executes the `threads` command in 3 seconds when run on the JVM's local machine.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\jdb.exe -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=xxx.yyy.com,port=7777
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Initializing jdb ...
> threads
Group system:
> threads
Group system:
  (java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler)0x7484                                                                  Reference Handler
  (java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread)0x7485                                                                   Finalizer
  (java.lang.Thread)0x7486                                                                                          ...
GC Daemon
  (java.lang.Thread)0x748b                                                                                          RMI RenewClean-
...
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation and packet sniffing, it appears that having a large number of threads in the remote process causes debugging packet congestion as well as a feedback loop of processing delays between the remote process debug agent and the remote debugger. Basically, the JVM debugging agent isn't engineered for high latency connections or debugging a large number of threads remotely. It also doesn't make an attempt to compress thread/stack/variable update information to lower transfer time to the debugger.

Our solution was eventually to add a thread debug mode to our product that reduced the various server thread pool sizes, then debugging was suddenly acceptably responsive again across overseas networks.

A future suggestion to the Java community would be to add a thread filter feature to both Eclipse and the Java Debug Agent so that only information for threads of interest is transmitted to the debugger after each code step is signalled.

Comment: I confirm that we had the same issue of debugging a remote JVM with many threads using Eclipse (eventhe latest Oxygen version). The same problematic environment can be perfectly debugged remotely using another IDE, such as NetBeans.